# JPA onetone embeddedid

Tags: jpa, composite-primary-key

I am working on building a relationship in JPA where I can split a file into multiple files while maintaining the original file relationship in a associative table.
I have `MyFile` entity and `FileRelationship` entity which is the associative Table with two columns: myFileId (primary-key), parentId).  Those two columns are foreign keys referencing MyFile id.

So I have two entities, MyFile.java and FileRelationship.java.  The MyFile can have one parent and parent can have more than one children.  The relationship is stored in FileRelationship table.

**MyFile.java**

```java
@Entity
public class MyFile implements Cloneable {  
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="MYFILE_SEQ", sequenceName="MYFILE_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="MYFILE_SEQ")
    private Long id;

    //get the parent in the fileRealtionship for this MyFile
    @OneToOne (mappedBy="myFile")
    private FileRelationship fileRelationship;
    ...
}
```

**FileRelationship.java**

```
@Entity
public class FileRelationship implements Serializable {     
    @EmbeddedId
    private MyFileId id;

    @MapsId("myFileId") 
    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="myFileId")
    private MyFile myFile;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parentId")
    private MyFile parent;
    ...
}
```

**MyFileId.java**

```
@Embeddable
public class MyFileId implements Serializable {
    private Long myFileId;

    public MyFileId() {
        super();
    }

    public MyFileId(Long myFileId) {
        super();
        this.myFileId = myFileId;
    }

    public Long getMyFileId() {
        return myFileId;
    }
    ...
}
```

I am not able save a relationship when I attempt to store a relationship. I keep getting

> org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null identifier

If I change the following in FileRelationship.java to ManyToOne then it works:

```
@MapsId("myFileId") 
@ManyToOne  //@OneToOne()
@JoinColumn(name="myFileId")
private MyFile myFile;
```

but then it would mean many `FileRelationship` entity can belong to one `myFile` entity which means `myFile` is not a primary key anymore.